# Select tab to open after submitting.

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Im working on a Laravel web application. In that application I have tabs one of which is a quiz written in PHP. When I submit the quiz the page reloads and the answers are returned but I cant get the page to load the tab with the quiz. Any suggestions.

The nav tab code

```
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Text</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#questions" aria-controls="questions" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Quiz</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#map" aria-controls="map" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tested Skills</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#video" aria-controls="video" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">YouTube Video</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The controller code

```
    public function comp001(Request $request){
$correct = "Correct";
$wrong = "Incorrect";
$q001 = Quiz::where('comp', '=', '001')->get();
//dump(Input::get('optionsRadios9'));

return view('competency001')
->withQ001($q001)
->withCorrect($correct)
->withWrong($wrong);

     }
```

The website
http://pprtestreview.com

Comment: You can pass the id of the appropriate tab to your view along with the other parameters.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on Page refresh you can activate `questions` tab 
so pass a some flag to trigger activateTab

```
activateTab('questions');

function activateTab(tab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Comment: You're not passing a boolean to `activateTab`. `'questions'` in your example is a string.